# MySQL: Getting a return code when calling a stored procedure within another stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

You have 2 MySQL stored procedures, both that select return codes at the end. You need to call 1 stored procedure within another, and get its return code. Is this possible?

Proc1:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE (IN...)
BEGIN
DECLARE ret_code
...UPDATE SOMETHING....
SELECT ret_code as return_code from dual;
END
```

Proc2:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE (IN...)
BEGIN
DECLARE returnVal
if(conditional true)
    ..Update something else..
    Set returnVal = x;
else
    call proc1(var1,...)
    Set returnVal = (ret_code obtained from proc1)
end if
select returnVal;
END
```

When calling proc1 within proc2, how can I get that ret_code that's selected at the end of proc1 within proc2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either use `CREATE FUNCTION` instead of `CREATE PROCEDURE`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION (...) RETURNS ...datatype...
BEGIN
DECLARE ret_code
...UPDATE SOMETHING....
RETURN ret_code;
END

CREATE FUNCTION (...) RETURNS ...datatype...
BEGIN
DECLARE returnVal
if(conditional true)
    ..Update something else..
    Set returnVal = x;
else
    Set returnVal = proc1(var1,...)
end if
RETURN returnVal;
END
```

or else specify an `OUT` parameter to the procedure, and use that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE (OUT ret_code ...datatype..., IN...)
BEGIN
...UPDATE SOMETHING....
Set ret_code = return_code;
END

CREATE PROCEDURE (OUT returnVal ...datatype..., IN...)
BEGIN
if(conditional true)
    ..Update something else..
    SET returnVal = x;
else
    call proc1(returnVal, var1,...)
end if
END
```

Comment: The OUT makes total sense, thanks. I was wondering if maybe there was some lesser known trick for accessing it through some global or something but this answers my question.